# take first result of php foreach and carry on

Tags: php, arrays, joomla, joomla-extensions

This is a very difficult question to ask but, lets try. I am using [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-showcase/19125) module for joomla i need tocreate an overide for it so that it takes the first result of

```
<?php foreach( $pages as $key => $list ): ?>
```

and places it in its own div and carries on with the statement. Please ask if any other information is needed here's the entire code for the override:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     mod_bt_contentslider - BT ContentSlider Module
 * @version     1.4
 * @created     Oct 2011

 * @author      BowThemes
 * @email       support@bowthems.com
 * @website     http://bowthemes.com
 * @support     Forum - http://bowthemes.com/forum/
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2012 Bowthemes. All rights reserved.
 * @license     http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL
 *
 */
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

if($modal){JHTML::_('behavior.modal');}
$document = JFactory::getDocument();

if(count($list)>0){?>
<div id="btcontentslider<?php echo $module->id; ?>" style="display:none;" class="span4 bt-cs<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx? ' bt-cs'.$params->get('moduleclass_sfx'):'';?>">
  <!--CONTENT-->
    <div class="slides_container" style="width:<?php echo $moduleWidth.";".$add_style;?>">
    <?php foreach( $pages as $key => $list ): ?>
        <div class="slide" style="width:100%;">
        <?php foreach( $list as $i => $row ): ?>
            <ul class="bt-row <?php if($i==0) echo 'bt-row-first'; else if($i==count($list)-1) echo 'bt-row-last' ?>"  style="width:100%" >
                <li class="bt-inner">
                <?php if( $row->thumbnail && $align_image != "center"): ?>
                    <a target="<?php echo $openTarget; ?>" class="bt-image-link<?php echo $modal? ' modal':''?>" title="<?php echo $row->title;?>" href="<?php echo $modal?$row->mainImage:$row->link;?>">
                      <img <?php echo $imgClass ?>  src="<?php echo $row->thumbnail; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->title?>"  style="width:<?php echo $thumbWidth ;?>px; float:<?php echo $align_image;?>;margin-<?php echo $align_image=="left"? "right":"left";?>:5px" title="<?php echo $row->title?>" />
                    </a> 
                <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if( $showTitle ): ?>
                    <a class="bt-title" target="<?php echo $openTarget; ?>"
                        title="<?php echo $row->title; ?>"
                        href="<?php echo $row->link;?>"> <?php echo $row->title_cut; ?> </a><br />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if( $row->thumbnail && $align_image == "center" ): ?>
                    <div class="bt-center">
                    <a target="<?php echo $openTarget; ?>"
                        class="bt-image-link<?php echo $modal? ' modal':''?>"
                        title="<?php echo $row->title;?>" href="<?php echo $modal?$row->mainImage:$row->link;?>">
                        <img <?php echo $imgClass ?> src="<?php echo $row->thumbnail; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->title?>"  style="width:<?php echo $thumbWidth ;?>px;" title="<?php echo $row->title?>" />
                    </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif ; ?>


                    <?php if( $show_intro ): ?>
                    <div class="bt-introtext">
                    <?php echo $row->description; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if( $showReadmore ) : ?>
                    <p class="readmore">
                        <a target="<?php echo $openTarget; ?>"
                            title="<?php echo $row->title;?>"
                            href="<?php echo $row->link;?>"> <?php echo JText::_('READ_MORE');?>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </li>
                <!--end bt-inner -->
            </ul>
            <!--end bt-row -->
            <!--CONTENT-->
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
        <!--end bt-main-item page   -->
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

    <?php if( $next_back && $totalPages  > 1  ) : ?>
    <a class="prev" href="#"></a><a class="next" href="#"></a> 
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
<!--end bt-container -->
<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if(typeof(btcModuleIds)=='undefined'){var btcModuleIds = new Array();var btcModuleOpts = new Array();}
    btcModuleIds.push(<?php echo $module->id; ?>);
    btcModuleOpts.push({
            slideEasing : '<?php echo $slideEasing; ?>',
            fadeEasing : '<?php echo $slideEasing; ?>',
            effect: '<?php echo $effect; ?>',
            preloadImage: '<?php echo $preloadImg; ?>',
            generatePagination: <?php echo $paging ?>,
            play: <?php echo $play; ?>,                     
            hoverPause: <?php echo $hoverPause; ?>, 
            slideSpeed : <?php echo $duration; ?>,
            autoHeight:<?php echo $autoHeight ?>,
            fadeSpeed : <?php echo $fadeSpeed ?>,
            equalHeight:<?php echo $equalHeight; ?>,
            width: <?php echo $moduleWidth=='auto'? "'auto'":$params->get( 'module_width', 0 ); ?>,
            height: <?php echo $moduleHeight=='auto'? "'auto'":$params->get( 'module_height', 0 ); ?>,
            pause: 100,
            preload: true,
            paginationClass: '<?php echo $butlet==1 ? 'bt_handles': 'bt_handles_num' ?>',
            generateNextPrev:false,
            prependPagination:true,
            touchScreen:<?php echo $touchScreen ?>
    });
</script>
<?php 
    // set position for bullet
    if($butlet) {
        $nav_top = (-1)*(int)$params->get( 'navigation_top', 0 );
        $nav_right = (-1)*(int)$params->get( 'navigation_right', 0 )+5;
        if(trim($params->get('content_title'))) $nav_top += 13;
        $document->addStyleDeclaration(
            $modid . ' ' . ($butlet == 1 ? '.bt_handles' : '.bt_handles_num') . '{'.
                'bottom: ' . '5% !important;'.
                'right: ' . '50% !important'.
            '}'
        );

    }
    // set responsive for mobile device
    if($moduleWidth=='auto'){
    $document->addStyleDeclaration(
        '
        @media screen and (max-width: 480px){.bt-cs .bt-row{width:100%!important;}}'
    );
    }
}
else
{ 
    echo '<div>No result...</div>'; 
} ?>
```

Any Help Greatly apreciated.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding here but you could simply have a flag that was set to false before the foreach and then inside the foreach check if that flag is false and create the div, and then set the div to true after

Comment: im really still very junior in PHP... so you could be right.. im just not sure how i guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this. basicly, set a boolean to only do something different to the first item:

```
<?php $first = true; ?>
<?php foreach( $pages as $key => $list ): ?>
<?php 
    if($first) {
        /* put this $list in its own div or whatever you need to do */
        $first = false;
    } else {
        ... //the default operation/code
?>
...
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete Edit:

Use a counter to know which iteration it is:

```
<?php $c = 0; // initialize counter
foreach( $pages as $key => $list ): 
if ($c++ == 0):
?>
this section will only run for the first element.

<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: i think he wants to put the first item in its own div (aka do something different with the first item), and then carry on with the rest.

Comment: that would work but i need to carry on putting the others in <ul><li>item</li></ul> except the first result needs to go into a div.

Comment: @kennypu thank you, i did not understand the first time dawid see my edit.

Comment: if you need to put the others in <ul><li> items then just add an 'else' statement to the 'if' mentioned by @Ibu and put in those list items